# Defining the type of a variable based on a third party library in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using the library `https://github.com/kizitonwose/CalendarView` for creating a calendar in kotlin.

I'm trying to follow the readme but the problem is that the docs doesn't specify how the variable `calendarView` is declared.

From the docs we add the following to the xml, which has the id `calendarView`:

```
<com.kizitonwose.calendarview.CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cv_dayViewResource="@layout/calendar_day_layout" />
```

It then goes on to show the usage:

```
calendarView.dayBinder = object : DayBinder<DayViewContainer> {
    // Called only when a new container is needed.
    override fun create(view: View) = DayViewContainer(view)
    
    // Called every time we need to reuse a container.
    override fun bind(container: DayViewContainer, day: CalendarDay) {
        container.textView.text = day.date.dayOfMonth.toString()
    }
}
```

Problem is that I don't see how `calendarView` is defined. My thought was:

```
val calendarView: CalendarView = findViewById(R.id.calendarView)
```

But `calendarView` does not have the attribute `dayBinder`.

So my question is, what should I specify as the type of `calendarView`?
ie:

```
val calendarView: <WHAT SHOULD BE HERE?> = findViewById(R.id.calendarView)
```

Or should it be defined a different way?

Options available for me to define `calendarView`:
[image]

Comment: "But calendarView does not have the attribute dayBinder." -- it is a property on `CalendarView`, based on [the source code](https://github.com/kizitonwose/CalendarView/blob/1.0.4/library/src/main/java/com/kizitonwose/calendarview/CalendarView.kt#L33-L37)

Comment: You're right, but either way, how should ```calendarView``` be initialised?

Comment: This should be correct: `val calendarView: CalendarView = findViewById(R.id.calendarView)` the way you have it.

Comment: Did you check that you imported the right `CalendarView`, not the `android.widget.CalendarView`? You might need to use `val calendarView: com.kizitonwose.calendarview.CalendarView = ...`. In Android Studio you can right click on the type `CalendarView` and choose Go To->Declaration to see which one it's pointing at.

Comment: I added the picture to the options I have, I don't see the one from ```com.kizitonwose```... am I missing something? I've added all the necessary stuff in the gradle files

Comment: what if you add `import com.kizitonwose.calendarview.CalendarView` at the top of the file?

Comment: That fixed the error, thank you. Should have checked that first. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is correct, but it's probably getting `android.widget.CalendarView`. Add the import for the third party library to the top of the file and it should work.

```
import com.kizitonwose.calendarview.CalendarView
```